# GitLab CI conditional source command in "before_script"

Tags: linux, docker, gitlab, debian, gitlab-ci

I have a project where I have several branches, the main brach, the develop branch and then n dynamic feature branches.

So for example the docker-build job in my GitLab CI Pipeline fetches some environment variables in the before_script section from a file called either .main.env or .develop.env (depending on the branch name) using the source command.

```yaml
docker-build:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: package
  tags:
    - deployment
  before_script:
    - source .${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}.env # || source .develop.env
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker build --build-arg SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILE=$SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILE -t $TAG_COMMIT -t $TAG_LATEST . -f Dockerfile
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker push $TAG_COMMIT
    - docker push $TAG_LATEST
```

As you can see I tried adding the conditional command `source .develop.env` in case the file in the first command wasn't found, this does not work though. It still throws an error saying that the file .SOME_FEATURE_BRANCH.env couldn't be found.

Now I'm wondering if there is any better way to solve this than making another job just for feature branches that simply source the .develop.env file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably better to just be explicit and check for the existence of the file.

```yaml
before_script:
  - |
    if [[ -f ".${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}.env" ]]; then
        source ".${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}.env"
    else
        source .develop.env
    fi
```

---

You could also accomplish something similar with `rules:variables:`, which can be handy if you want to decouple your shell scripts from being concerned about details of the CI environment.

```yaml
job:
  variables:  # default env file
    ENV_FILE: ".develop.env" 
  rules:
  - exists: ".${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}.env"
    variables: # override when this file exists
      ENV_FILE: ".${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}.env"
  - when: on_success
  before_script:
    - source $ENV_FILE
```

Comment: I've done it the "scripty" way, does seem to work without any issues, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error will be written to STDERR when the first source is run and fails. Then it will go on to execute the second source. If you want to supress the error message in the first source command you can redirect the STDOUT to /dev/null.

```
docker-build:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: package
  tags:
    - deployment
  before_script:
    - source .${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}.env 2>/dev/null || source .develop.env
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker build --build-arg SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILE=$SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILE -t $TAG_COMMIT -t $TAG_LATEST . -f Dockerfile
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker push $TAG_COMMIT
    - docker push $TAG_LATEST
```

Comment: Thank you, it does seem to work when I try it out locally with two different environment files, but when adding it to the pipeline yml, the log output would just not show an error at all, but skip all the commands defined in the script section, and exit with status code 2.